# Updating FBX SDK Model loading from 2012.2 to 2014.1 SDK

Tags: c++, fbx, .lib

I've just ported over and updated a bunch of FBX model loading code I had that worked with Direct X 10 to try and make it work with Direct X 11. Since that time, the FBX SDK I was using has been updated.

In my old program I linked to the following lib:

```
fbxsdk-2012.2-mdd.lib
```

Now, clearly I can't link to this as I don't have 2012.2 on my system. So, my thinking would be simply changing 2012.2 to 2014.1, but this didn't work and lead to the following error:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'fbxsdk-2014.1-mdd.lib'
```

So I tried to some googleing to see what the updated version of fbxsdk-2012.2-mdd.lib is. But I can't find anything. I tried taking out linking ot the 2014.1 lib but I get the following errors:

> Error 36  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl fbxsdk_2014_1::FbxAssert(char const *,char const *,unsigned int,char const *)" (?FbxAssert@fbxsdk_2014_1@@YAXPBD0I0@Z) referenced in function "public: int & __thiscall fbxsdk_2014_1::FbxArray::operatorconst " (??A?$FbxArray@H@fbxsdk_2014_1@@QBEAAHH@Z)

So, looking in the FBX sample directory I opened up the ViewScene sample to see what it lib it linked to and I see that it wanted the following:

```
libfbxsdk-md.lib
```

So I did the same. But, my program claims it cannot open the file. And I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

Has anyone successfully managed to load FBX models into a Directx 11 application using 2014.1? If so, what do I need to do to get the correct lib linked?

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem this is what i did ...i read it around here in stackoverflow somewhere
anyway

```
"first change parameters, tools->option->debugging->symbol->server,yes thenCtrl+F5,then you will see amazing things "
```

Answer (score 0):

libfbxsdk-md.lib is in both debug/release lib folders, so Visual Studio is confused. The full debug/release lib folder path in the Visual Studio property pages must be included separately for debug/release settings.